# How to parse @{TEST TAGS} into only the Tags, eliminating current formatting?

Tags: robotframework

Situation.. I have two tags defined, then I try to output them to the console. What comes out seems to be similar to an array, but I'd like to remove the formatting and just have the actual words outputted.

Here's what I currently have:

```
    [Tags]  ready   ver10
    Log To Console  \n@{TEST TAGS}
```

And the result is

```
['ready', 'ver10']
```

So, how would I chuck the `['`, the `', '` and the `']`, thus only retaining the words `ready` and `ver10`?

Note: I was getting `[u'ready', u'ver10']` - but once I got some advice to make sure I was running Python3 RobotFramework - after uninstalling `robotframework` via `pip`, and now only having `robotframework` installed via `pip3`, the `u` has vanished. That's great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. For example, you could use a loop, or you could convert the list to a string before calling [log to console](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console)

### Using a loop.

Since the data is a list, it's easy to iterate over the list:

```
FOR  ${tag}  IN  @{Test Tags}
    log to console  ${tag}
END
```

### Converting to a string

You can use the [evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to convert the list to a string of values separated by a newline. Note: you have to use two backslashes in the call to `evaluate` since both robot and python use the backslash as an escape character. So, the first backslash escapes the second so that python will see `\n` and convert it to a newline.

```
${tags}=  evaluate  "\\n".join($test_tags)
log to console  \n${tags}
```